# Group generated by normal subgroup and one more element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose I have a normal subgroup $N$ in $G$, and suppose there exists an element of order $p$ in $G/N$; i.e., some coset $gN \in G/N$ has order $p$.

I'm trying to find another subgroup in $G$ that has order $p|N|$ and contains $N$, with the above information. My intuition tells me that it should be $\bigcup_k g^k N$ (the union of these particular cosets of $N$ generated by $gN$), but am having trouble seeing how to show this rigorously. Is this even true in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true. Check that it is a subgroup. First show closure under multiplication and inversion and then argue that the cosets $g^kN$ are disjoint for $0\le k<p$ (distinct cosets are disjoint!) in order to justify the claim that the union has order $p|N|$. When showing closure be sure to make use of the fact that $aN=Na$ for all $a\in G$, so elements of $N$ can be "passed across" other elements although they (the elements from $N$) get changed in the process.

More generally, there is a correspondence between subgroups $A\le G/N$ and intermediate groups lying in between as $N\le B\le G$ (where $N\trianglelefteq G$). In particular, we get $A$ from $B$ by projecting through $G\to G/N$, and get $B$ from $A$ by taking the preimage. You may wish to prove this fact too as above; it uses the same exact arguments. (This is the *lattice isomorphism theorem*.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation and the extra reference. I have one last question. I originally wanted to claim that this new subgroup is generated by $N$ and $g$, but I think this is wrong. $N=(gN)^p=g^p N$ implies that $g^p \in N$, not that $g^p=1$. Is there some way to describe this new subgroup in a way similar to what I attempted here?

Comment: @blf You are correct that this new subgroup is generated by $N$ and $g$. The fact that $g^p\in N$ but $g^p$ is not necessarily $1$ doesn't change anything. The most conceptual description of this new subgroup is as the union of the cosets contained in $\langle gN\rangle\le G/N$, exactly as you have. Otherwise what kind of description are you looking for?

Comment: Oh! Ok, but what can we say about the order of $g$ in $G$? Just that it's the product of $p$ with a factor of $|N|$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$